# Evaluating $\zeta(4)$ using iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, zeta-functions, iterated-integrals

I'd like to evaluate $\zeta(4)$ using iterated integrals.  We already know the numerical answer, so it remains to set up the integral and do some of the steps.  From the recipe of [Ihara-Kaneko-Zagier](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1112/S0010437X0500182X/fulltext.pdf) one has:
$$ \zeta(4) = \int_{1 > t_1 > t_2 > t_3 > t_4 > 0} \omega(t_1) \omega(t_2)\omega(t_3) \omega(t_4)
= \int_{1 > t_1 > t_2 > t_3 > t_4 > 0} 
\frac{dt_1}{t_1}
\frac{dt_2}{t_2}
\frac{dt_3}{t_3}
\frac{dt_4}{(1-t_4)}$$
Does this look correct? The domain of integration is a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) (a [5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell)). What are some of the intermediate steps to evaluating this integral?

Answer (score 1):

In pages $8-9$ of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) it is proved that by evaluating 
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(x)\log^2(1-x)}{x}\,dx $$
(which, of course, can be *unfolded* into a multiple integral) in two different ways we have
$$ \zeta(4) = \frac{2}{5}\zeta(2)^2 $$
even without knowing the identity $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which, on its turn, can be proved by essentially squaring the Taylor series of the $\arctan$ or $\arcsin$ functions. Many equivalent approaches are outlined in [this historical thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro/617710#617710).

Comment: your notes are fascinating!! This paper of Kaneko-Ihara-Zagier starts you off with a *specific* multiple integral.   So I'm asking to do the computation from there... I guess the exercise is to show that RHS is indeed $\zeta(4)$.  I"m not even sure they demonstrate $\zeta(4) \in \pi^4 \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @cactus314: by my initial integral should be equivalent to IKZ's one by writing $\log(x)$ as $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt_1}{t_1}$ etc, then performing simple substitutions.